# How to store mysql date in Java , which type of variable to use?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a `MySQL` table , some columns and one of them is of `DATE` type.
Now , in Java i have fields for columns , but when i get to date i just don't know what to do ...

```
package com.keeptrack.model;
public class Racun {
    int id;
    String uplatilac;
    String svrha_uplate;
    String primalac;
    int sifra_placanja;
    String valuta;
    Double iznos;
    Long racun_primaoca;
    int model;
    String poziv_na_broj;
    ?????? date;
}
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Please minimize your example code to focus on the issue at hand. And remember that Stack Overflow is an English language site.

Comment: The topic of storing Java date-time values in MySQL has been covered many many times. Search before posting, and explain how your Question is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `java.time.LocalDate`

MySQL's `DATE` type is used for values with a date part but no time part, so you're better off to use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) API.

Another variant is the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) API. Use this if you want to represent a date as well as a time i.e.  MySQL's `DATETIME` type would require [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object to represent it on the client side (Java program).

As an aside, avoid exposing fields to the outside world. make them all `private` to enforce encapsulation and only provide getters and setters where required.

Comment: OK ty , i tried LocalDate and it worked , but later in the program i had a PreparedStatement ps ........ and when i try ps.setDate (10,r.date); it says that LocalDate cannot be converted into Date so i used just Date and imported java.sql.Date;

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic Using the java.time in JDBC requires a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later.  `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalDate );` for a MySQL `DATE` column.